# What is the meaning of operators in regression or anova formulas in R

Tags: r, regression, anova

I was wondering, what is the meaning of operators in anova or regression formulas in R

For example

- "**+**" aov <- aov(x~time+sample, data=data) -> repeated mesures anova?
- "*****" aov <- aov(x~time*sample, data=data) -> two way anova?
- "**/**" aov <- aov(x~time/sample, data=data) -> ?
- "**:**" aov <- aov(x~time:sample, data=data) -> ?

And also are there more operators for this kind of formulas?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Formula/vignettes/Formula.pdf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The formulas in R have their own mini-language. You can have some detailed information in the R session with

```
help(formula)
```

which you can also find [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html).

For the sake of the example, let's say that you predict $Z$ from $X$ and $Y$ and let's drop the error terms.

$Z \sim X + Y$ means that you fit and additive model $Z_i = X_i + Y_i$

$Z \sim X * Y$ means that you fit a model with interactions $Z_i = X_i + Y_i + X_i  Y_i$

$Z \sim X / Y$ means that you fit a model with "nested" interactions $Z_i = X_i + X_i  Y_i$

$Z \sim X : Y$ means that you fit a model with only interactions $Z_i = X_i  Y_i$

You also have the $-$, ^ and $\%in\%$ operators described in the help page. The $-$ operator is mostly used for removing the intercept and the others are redundant with the ones shown above.